# OOPS and abstraction

Tags: c#, oop

I am not a native English speaker. So, I am asking this question to know what it means to use the word 'abstraction' when teaching C# or any other OOP languages. Most of the books say 'classes allow develeopers to create abstractions'. Does the word abstraction here represent an aspect of the problem the developer is trying to solve ? If so, how is it in line with the general meaning of the word 'abstraction' in OOPS that basically says expose only what is necessary to the outside world and make everything else an implementation detail ? May be, we can define the word 'abstraction' as representing some aspect of the problem with a particular attention on hiding everything but what is essential to talk to the class. Any comments are much appreciated.

Comment: *OOPS and abstraction* sounds like a Sundance movie title :). As for your question, abstraction doesn't imply 'hiding' as you said. But make abstract, so create a concept rather that a class that you can use as is.

Comment: Belongs on [programmers.se] if anywhere.

Comment: @Mathieu Imbert I am not saying the word 'abstraction' means hiding. I am only saying abstraction achieves hiding in the sense that when you abstract something you expose only what is absolutely needed to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> classes allow developers to create abstractions

In the context of OOP, it would seem this simply refers to what a class is: a representation of an object.  It's abstract in the sense that it only describes the object, without embodying it.  The actual instances of the class (objects) then realize the abstraction.

It might be helpful if you could post an actual quote, so that we can gauge its meaning in context.

Comment: It's not a quote I grabbed from somewhere. The quotes around the sentence might have prompted you to think that it is quote from some book. But that is not so. I phrased this sentence from what I understood reading different books. I would like to accept this as an answer for your choice words; "without embodying it" and "realizing the abstraction". Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

An abstration is a simplified way of representing a more complicated, often real-world concept. Or, as noted in the comments, it is a *model* of a real-world concept. If you are creating an application to manage sales of loaves of bread, you may have an object like the following:

```
public class Loaf
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan BakingTime { get; set; }
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The `Loaf` class is an abstraction for a real loaf of bread, as it simplifies (abstracts) it to a point where it is suitable for manipulation in a programming context.

Comment: You could say that an abstraction is a **model** of a real-world concept.

Comment: +1. I would also like to point out another aspect of abstraction. `Abstraction` can also mean to lift things on a higher logical level by hiding details. `Math.Sin(x)` is an abstraction of a loop calculating a Taylor series. By using `Math.Sin(x)` you don't care how the result is obtained.